# How do I check if a customer purchased a product using one-time pricing with the Stripe API?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

With the Stripe API, I can list the active subscriptions for a particular customer using the [List subsriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/list) endpoint. However, I give customers the option to make a one-time purchase of my product (for lifetime access).

[image]

Given a `customer_id`, how can I see if they ever purchased the lifetime access to my product.

Comment: How are you taking payment from them using that one time price? Checkout payment mode? One off invoices?

Comment: @BrendanMoore Checkout payment mode.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that searching for succeeded [PaymentIntents](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/search?lang=node) is the straight way:

```
let custId = 'cus_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
let lifeTimePrice = 7500;

const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.search({
  query: 'status:\'succeeded\' AND customer:\'' + custId + '\' AND amount:\'' + lifeTimePrice + '\'',
});
```

Comment: This way you code your purchase identity with the amount. Looks not very reliable. What if you later add some other products with the same price?

Comment: @DmitryKlochkov You can always use `metadata` in your own way.